# Finding closed form equation given integral, derivative, and value constraints.

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, minimal-polynomials

Apologies if this has been asked before, or has a simple answer that I am overlooking/missing. I am looking to see if it is possible to define a closed-form solution $\phi(x)$ given constraints without using some sort of curve fitting/approximate solution. I think there is probably a way to do this with matrices that I am overlooking, and I would be very grateful if someone has some insight or can point me in the right direction to solive this

Firstly, we know the following about our values/parameters:

1. $T_0,T_1\in[0,1]$;
2. $T_0<T_1$;
3. $p\in [0,1]$; and
4. $\tau = T_0 + (T_1-T_0)(1-p)$.

We are looking for the smallest n$^{th}$ polynomial that satsifies the following properties:

1. $\phi(T_0)=0$;
2. $\phi(T_1)=1$;
3. $\phi'(T_0)=0$;
4. $\phi'(T_1)=0$; and
5. $\int_{T_0}^{T_1}\phi(x)dx=p(T_1-T_0)$.

We also want $\phi'(x) \geq 0$ for $x\in[T_0, T_1]$, so monotonic.

If possible, we would also like:

- $\phi(\tau)=p$; and
- $\phi''(\tau)=0$.

but this isn't a strict requirement (it just would be nice). I have found a closed form solution that is piece-wise quadratic, but it lacks smoothness where the pieces meet. I know this cannot be done with a cubic polynomial (except when $p=0.5$), but I think it could be done with a 4th or perhaps 5th order polynomial. I started calculating by hand under this assumption, but it became incredibly messy incredibly quickly.

Is there a quicker and easier way to work this out, or should I just commit to doing it (carefully!) by hand.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have $5$ linear equations, and a polynomial of degree $4$ has $5$ coefficients, so you should expect a unique solution to these.  This may or may not satisfy the non-negativity requirement on $\phi'$.  If it doesn't, you'll want to try degree $5$, where you should have a one-parameter family of solutions.

For simplicity, we may take $T_0 = 0$ and $T_1 = 1$ (for other values, we can translate and scale).  Then the solution for degree $4$ is
$$  \phi(t) =  (30 p - 12) t^2 + (-60 p + 28) t^3 + (30 p - 15) t^4$$
For $2/5 \le p \le 3/5$ this solution is nondecreasing (these being the values of $p$ for which $\phi''(0) = 0$ and $\phi''(1) = 0$ respectively).
For values of $p$ outside this interval you'll want to try a higher-degree
polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, I did think that this would be the case! Is there an easier way to do this than by hand with back substitution in order to get a general solution, or do I just need to take a breath and do it by hand? Thanks again for a timely and concise answer.

Comment: I used Maple; you could try Wolfram Alpha.